# how to send the url between href tag to outside form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So..this code allow me to send the target link to outside form and almost working good ...

```
//auto send onclick
 $(function(){
   $("body").on("click", ".link-id", function(){
       $('#content').val($(this).html()); 
         $('#main_input').submit(); 
       return false;
    });
  });
```

The problem here when i clicked to send i cant get url and send title only...
i need it to send href="the dynamic url here" not the title

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoId + '" class="link-id">' + title + '</a>
```

Comment: you want `$('#content').val(this.href);`

Comment: you mean to replace $('#content').val($(this).html());  with $('#content').val(this.href);

Comment: Yes... assuming I am understanding correctly

Comment: Thank you so much sir..is working good now 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the current link's href value in the input use

```
$('#content').val(this.href);
```

Instead of

```
$('#content').val($(this).html());
```